# java unmarshell JAXB_FRAGMENT

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an object that generate from xsd:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "myClass", propOrder = {
    "id",
    "code"
})
public class MyClass {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String id;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String code;
    ...

}
```

And I get a string: `<id>1234dddd</id><code>ddsw</code>`

I want unmarshell this string to object of `MyClass`.

```
try (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml)) {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<MyClass> jaxbElement = (JAXBElement<MyClass>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    return  jaxbElement.getValue();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Ошибка десериализации", e);
}
```

But I got an error: `unexpected element (uri:"", local:"id"). Expected elements are (none)`
I can't change MyClass because it generated, how can I get an object of it from string?

Answer (score 0):

The solution shown here does these two things:

1. It uses a specific `Unmarshaller` method to declare `MyClass` to be the target object.
2. It uses `MyClassStringReader` to envelop the XML fragment in a `<myClass>...</myClass>` root element.

The output is:

```
myClass: org.example.myclass.MyClass@6b9651f3
  id...: 1234dddd
  code.: ddsw
```

This `unmarshal` method can be used when the JAXB class does not declare itself to be a `@XmlRootElement`. It declares the target class *explicitly*.

```
<T> JAXBElement<T>
unmarshal(javax.xml.transform.Source source, Class<T> declaredType)
```

Although the method needs an XML `Source` parameter, this can easily be created from an I/O reader or stream object, as shown in the demo.

This demo uses a custom reader class named `MyClassStringReader`, see farther below. Instead of using this approach, the XML fragment to be unmarshaled could have been wrapped in the `<myClass>...</myClass>` root element using `String` concatenation; but, the custom reader is a nice demonstration of I/O decoration and it could be used as the template for a file or other stream based reader where concatenation is a poor option.

**Demo.java**

```
package org.example.myclass;

import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String txt = "<id>1234dddd</id><code>ddsw</code>";
        try
        {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            try (StringReader reader = new MyClassStringReader(txt))
            {
                // reader: "<myClass><id>1234dddd</id><code>ddsw</code></myClass>";
                Source source = new StreamSource(reader);
                Object obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, MyClass.class);
                if ( obj instanceof JAXBElement )
                {
                    MyClass myClass = ((JAXBElement<MyClass>) obj).getValue();
                    println("myClass: " + myClass);
                    println("  id...: " + myClass.id);
                    println("  code.: " + myClass.code);
                }
                else
                    println("Object.:" + obj);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Ошибка десериализации", ex);
        }
    }

    private static void println(String str)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

This `MyClassStringReader` class extends `java.io.StringReader` to envelop any string containing *only* the sub-elements of a `myClass` element with the required root element. XML always needs a root element. It overrides all the public methods used by an abstract `Reader` by delegating most of the work to its `StringReader` super instance. This is a quick implementation that needs thorough testing for wider use.

**MyClassStringReader.java**

```
package org.example.myclass;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

/**
 * Envelop a {@link StringReader} with a root element.
 */
public class MyClassStringReader extends StringReader
{
    private static final String ROOT_OPEN = "<myClass>";
    private static final String ROOT_CLOSE = "</myClass>";
    private final StringReader ROOT_OPEN_READER = new StringReader(ROOT_OPEN);
    private final StringReader ROOT_CLOSE_READER = new StringReader(ROOT_CLOSE);
    
    /**
     * Construct with string.
     * @param str The string to stream.
     */
    public MyClassStringReader(String str)
    {
        super(str);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException
    {
        int nextChar = ROOT_OPEN_READER.read();
        if ( nextChar < 0 )
        {
            nextChar = super.read();
            if ( nextChar < 0 )
                nextChar = ROOT_CLOSE_READER.read();
        }
        return nextChar;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException
    {
        // Guard len
        if ( len > cbuf.length)
            len = cbuf.length;
        
        // Skip offset characters
        int nextChar = 0;
        while ( (--off > 0) && ((nextChar = read()) >= 0) );
        
        // Read len or less characters
        int counter = 0;
        if ( nextChar >= 0 )
        {
            while ( (counter < len) && ((nextChar = read()) >= 0) )
                cbuf[counter++] = (char) nextChar;
        }
        
        // Return number of characters read or EOS
        return (counter > 0 ) ? counter : -1;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean ready() throws IOException
    {
        return ROOT_OPEN_READER.ready() || super.ready() || ROOT_CLOSE_READER.ready();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void reset() throws IOException
    {
        ROOT_OPEN_READER.reset();
        super.reset();
        ROOT_CLOSE_READER.reset();
    }
    
    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException
    {
        long s = n;
        if ( n > 0L )
        {
            if ( ROOT_OPEN_READER.ready() )
                s -= ROOT_OPEN_READER.skip(s);
            if ( (s > 0) && super.ready() )
                s -= super.skip(s);
            if ( (s > 0) && ROOT_CLOSE_READER.ready() )
                s -= ROOT_CLOSE_READER.skip(s);
        }
        else if ( n < 0L )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("skip value is negative");
        return (n-s);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mark(int readAheadLimit) throws IOException
    {
        if ( ROOT_OPEN_READER.ready() )
            ROOT_OPEN_READER.mark(readAheadLimit);
        else if (super.ready() )
            super.mark(readAheadLimit);
        else if ( ROOT_CLOSE_READER.ready() )
            ROOT_CLOSE_READER.mark(readAheadLimit);
    }
}
```